# Update an Observable Collection based on DateTime Condition

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I have a WPF C# desktop Application.

I have attached a DataGrid to an Observable Collection via my ViewModel class.

The Collection is derived from my SQL Lite database.

I use LINQ to populate this collection and in my LINQ I am selecting by todays current date.

Now, should I update this collection by calling a timer event (periodically) or is there a 'clever' way to do this?

I have not posted my code becuase I think the scenario is pretty straight forward BUT I will update my question if people want me to..

Comment: What exactly is *update* you mean? E.g. is it hiding old records, displaying newly added or what?

Comment: @Sinatr Hi, thanks for asking me.  There would be 2 entry points..  1 when a record is entered and 1 when a record has become more than a day old.  I know I could put the updater/timer at this entry points. Just wanted to know if there was a better way as I am new to WPF..

Comment: So you will hide old records (from yesterday) one by one and add new (which was just added). The complete update (re-creating `ObservableCollection`) is indeed not very optimal (depends on how many records will be removed+added). You can use linq to query only "new" items from database and add them to `ObservableCollection`. And delete those items from beginning of it which `DateTime` is expired.

Comment: @Sinatr Hi, yes I believe that is the way to go - thanks